# How to get the required value from the existing value when there is no suffix?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to use regular expression extractor concept in Jmeter. By using regEx concept I'm able to get the required token id's. And for all I'm using regEx as (.*?). So this is working fine when we have constant prefix and suffix text/values.

But in this case, there is no suffix,

Ex: Key is = @bluerelay.com/a43a816dcdd14873bd5757b3a3709d5c,

[ClickHereForImageForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGEXQ.png)

I want to take the key ID into a variable with using RegEx. I have tried to get it with (.*?) but it didn't work, it returns the full value, not the required part. It'd be excellent if you could give any suggestion.

The source value is:

```
https://navitus-internal-app.bluerelay.com/#/token/systemadministrator@bluerelay.com/a43a816dcdd14873bd5757b3a3709d5c
```

The expected result is to extract `a43a816dcdd14873bd5757b3a3709d5c` from the above URL and put it into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to get last text after `/` sign

```
 (.*)\/(\w+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpVi80/1)

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine. thank you. 
I have changed something like this: @bluerelay.com\/(\w+)